# sending the results of org-mode block execution to another buffer

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to be emulate something similar to using a repl with clojure/cider using org-mode  where the results of the evaluation are not put in directly into the document but sent to the `repl` buffer.

Is there a way to be able to configure this?

Comment: Using a `:session` header? See [Environment of a Code block](https://orgmode.org/manual/Environment-of-a-Code-Block.html#Environment-of-a-Code-Block)

Comment: @NickD, happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output silent :cache no :eval yes
echo "Hello"
#+END_SRC
```

In addition to @NickD's suggestion of `:session`